# Unable to have a tab completion of system variables without a backslash

Tags: bash, tab-completion

My inputrc is empty. I use Bash.

**Problem:**
I am at

```
cd $te
```

I press Tab, and I get

```
cd \$test
```

**How can you have the tab completion without the backslash in Bash?**

Comment: Do you maybe have a file in the current directory named "$test" ?

Comment: I see nothing that I would call a "flash" (in *any* direction). Could you elaborate?

Comment: @marcog: Ah. Make sense, and I think Rick wins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. In Bash, a $ is used in the retrieval of variables. For example:

```
SWEETVAR='hi'
echo $SWEETVAR
```

Because of this, a $ in the name of a file or folder must be escaped, else it is interpreted as a var.

Comment: @Allyn: How can you have a var instead of a system var in Bash, such that you do not need the backslash for escaping.

Comment: You apparently mean with a var an alias.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in MacPorts.

It has an old version of Bash_completion.

The newest version has the following in

```
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

while I have the following after executing the command

```
$complete | grep cd
complete -o filenames -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

I sent a comment to MacPorts' irc to update bash-completion @20060301 (sysutils).

Answer (score 0):

I finally moved to Zsh.
It solved the problem for me.